# How to remove repeated date tick labels

Tags: matlab, plot, axis-labels

I'm trying to plot 63 years of monthly data and some labels are repeating (indicated by arrows), illustrated by the following figure:

[image]

In order to handle x-labels, I used the following code:

```
xdate = datenum (datestring2, 'yyyy/mm');
plot (xdate,data1.data(:,4), 'b', xdate,data1.data(:,6),'r', ...
xdate,data1.data(:,8),'k', xdate,data1.data(:,10),'g');
xtic=xdate(1):12:xdate(end); 
set(gca,'XTick',xtic);
datetick('x', 'mm/yyyy', 'keepticks');
```

How can I solve that issue?

Comment: Looks like you can do this just by changing the step size in the line `xtic=xdate(1):12:xdate(end);`. For example: `xtic=xdate(1):24:xdate(end);`

Comment: Is `keepticks` necessary for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit the [carryover](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/carryover-in-date-vectors-and-strings.html) feature of [`datenum()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html):

```m
out = datenum(2000,1:14,1);
```

Let's verify:

```m
datestr(out)
ans =
01-Jan-2000
01-Feb-2000
01-Mar-2000
01-Apr-2000
01-May-2000
01-Jun-2000
01-Jul-2000
01-Aug-2000
01-Sep-2000
01-Oct-2000
01-Nov-2000
01-Dec-2000
01-Jan-2001
01-Feb-2001
```

Now set them as `Xtick`:

```m
set(gca,'Xtick',out)
```

**EDIT: use start end dates**

```m
% Provide example initial and final date
in = '20100324';
fi = '20130215';

% Decompose with datevec, count number of months, and skip one month if day > 1
infi    = datevec({in,fi},'yyyymmdd');
nmonths = diff(infi(:,1:2))*[12 1]' + infi(1,2);
skipone = infi(1,3) ~= 1;

% Calculate dates 
out = datenum(infi(1), (infi(1,2) + skipone):nmonths, 1);
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me about carryover. As I was writing my (convoluted) code, I was thinking "wouldn't it be nice if..." but never thought to check. Your solution is definitely cleaner than mine.

Comment: @Oleg Komarov the carryover is very simple to do. And it works great! Thanks!

Comment: I am glad to see @SauloCarvalho decided to change his vote and accept this answer over mine - although I think it would be good to show how this would actually be done for his situation (with an arbitrary start and end date somewhere in the middle of a year). I had tried to do that with an edit to my answer... and it didn't end up that much cleaner than what I had! Consider it a challenge :-)

Comment: @FLoris I got the message, by keeping d1(1), the script gets more automatic.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression `xtic=xdata(1):12:xdate(end)` says that you want a tick every 12 days; often that means you will get two (or even three) repeated months. A quick and dirty solution is

```
xtic = xdata(1):30:xdate(end);
```

But that may in some situations skip February, and will be wrong when you run for a large number of months.

To get around this properly, you need to place ticks at the first of every month. A possible way to do that is this:

```
xdate = datenum(datestring2, 'yyyy/mm');
d1 = datevec(xdate(1)); % [year, month, date, hour, min, sec]
d2 = datevec(xdate(end)+30); % one month past the last data point
nm = ceil((xdate(end) - xdate(1))*12/365); % whole number of months
mv = mod((1:nm) + d1(2) - 2, 12) + 1;  % months
yv = d1(1) + floor(((1:nm) + d1(2) - 1)/12); % years
ymdv = [yv' mv' ones(nm,1)];  % year, month, day for each tic
xtic = datenum(ymdv); % will turn this into "the first of every month"
```

**EDIT** Oleg Komarov's answer points to a much cleaner way to generate tics at every first of the month - this is using the fact that `datenum` can cope with months greater than 12. You could probably make the above code a little more compact and cleaner by using that approach (for example, you could leave out the `mod` operation for `mv`, and just use d1(1) for the year). But sometimes being explicit about what you are doing isn't a bad thing.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I need. I didn't know about February, that's why the ticks are not matching with y-values. Great!! Many thanks!